# One language for two different states

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization, multilingual

I have an application that supports two languages ​​- Czech and English. If the device is set to Czech - application is in Czech, if it is set at a different language, then the application is in English. It works well, but I need to be application in Czech language for Slovaki. How it easiest to do? Thank you for your response.

Comment: copy your localisable file and use it for Slovak localisation?

Comment: I wonder why you don't want to do a separate Slovak translation. How much work would that be to get a Slovak friend to translate it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best option if you don't want to set the Czech as the default language is to create a new localization file for Slovak and use the same strings as your Czech file. This way the default language will still be english for everywhere except Czech and Slovak.

Comment: If you don't want to maintain two files (In can be painfull to always make sure both file are in sync). You can create a script to copy automagically the content of the first file (Czech) in the second file (Slovak) after every build.